# How XML compression algorithms (example XMill) are so fast?

Tags: xml, algorithm, xml-parsing, compression, lossless-compression

I was studying an XML compression algorithm named [XMill](https://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~dilant/cs175/%5BAlex_Baron_2%5D.pdf). I tried to implement it myself in Java. There are lots of XMLs at [this link](http://xmlcompbench.sourceforge.net/Dataset.html), I used a structural XML (contains only tags) of "EXI-Telecomp" for my experiment (EXI-Telecomp_Structural.xml). Accordingly, I also made a dictionary for the structured part which looked like the picture below. [image: picture below]

I also downloaded the [original implementation of XMill](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xmill/).

EXI-Telecomp_Structural.xml is a very large XML (5530628 bytes). It is taking me minutes to just go through all the tags once, let alone the option of substituting tags from the dictionary. But the [actual implementation of XMill](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xmill/) is doing it in seconds. And according to [this survey paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000009000142), these algorithms do not take more than 10 seconds. After all, how are these algorithms working? I mean, how can all the structured parts (tags) of an XML file that takes minutes to read be substituted in a few seconds?

Comment: It is very unlikely the post get any attention without any language tag... and no code.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Not necessarily. It's more an algorithm question than a language question.

Comment: 5Mb is not a very large XML document these days, and if it is taking you minutes to process it then you are doing something badly wrong. My rule of thumb for processing large XML files (and of course it varies greatly depending on many factors) is about 1 minute per gigabyte.